# Can you import a function from an external JavaScript file with nodejs into an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a web page with a basic/filter search list, but it searches through data from txt files and returns the names of files that include the requested results. So I need to run a function that pulls data from the aforementioned txt files from a JavaScript file with NodeJS that can use readFileSync on the server-side and then return the results to an HTML file on the client side.

Here's the JS file, function.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('functioncall.html');

//The function run by the HTML file
function myFunction() {
    var nameArray = ['./File1.txt', './File2.txt'], resultArray = [], input, filter, ul, li, i, nameValue, fileText;

    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");  
    
    //Run through the file names and check if the requested text exists in the file, then push the name into an array if successful, else null
    For (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        nameValue = nameArray[i];
        
        fileText = fs.readFileSync(nameValue, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}).value.toUpperCase();

        if (fileText.indexOf(filter) >= 0) { 
          resultArray.push(nameValue);
        }
        else{
          resultArray.push(null);
        }
    }
    //If the search function gets a hit, display the name in the HTML file
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (resultArray[i] != null) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
   }
}


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
}).listen(3000);
```

And here's the HTML file, functioncall.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>File Search</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for text.." title="Type in text">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">File1.txt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">File2.txt</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell, with NodeJS running, the HTML file can't find the function. I understand this may be an issue with the client-side HTML file not being able to communicate with the server-side JS file, but I've gone searching and I haven't found a solution that has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Node JS is not used for client side logic. It looks like you're trying to create a server on the client, which doesn't make much sense. I would recommend doing more research into client side and server side Javascript before trying to move forward with your project.